# only old tensorflow version found when installing my new package from pypi

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pypi

I have put a package on test.pypi which does require tensorflow>=1.15.0. However, when I install it using

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ kmeanstf==0.7.0a4
```

I get the message

```
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting kmeanstf==0.7.0a4
Downloading https://testfiles.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/80/faf86ac10310e12015709d9763de9c0ebcf33df1f0bc884448993001ae8e/kmeanstf-0.7.0a4-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow>=1.15.0 (from 
kmeanstf==0.7.0a4) (from versions: 0.12.1, 2.0.0a0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow>=1.15.0 (from kmeanstf==0.7.0a4)
```

However, on pypi all Versions of tensorflow are present (including 1.15.0 and 2.0.0): https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history

When I lower the requirements to just 'tensorflow' (is done in kmeanstf==0.7.0a1), the version 0.12.1 from tensorflow is installed which is much too ancient for my package. It is however, one of the two versions mentioned in the above error message. Is 0.12.1 indeed the default on pypi?

What can I do here (apart from asking the users of my package to install tensorflow themselves)?

```
pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from 
/home/.../miniconda2/envs/empty/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forced the index URL to be https://test.pypi.org/simple/ so `pip` looks for tensorflow at https://test.pypi.org/project/tensorflow/ and there're only 2 versions that have downloadable wheels suitable for your platform.

If you want to install `kmeanstf` from `test.pypi.org` and `tensorflow` from `pypi.org` you need to provide an extra URL:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ kmeanstf==0.7.0a4
```